# For loop with condition only

Tags: c++, for-loop

Can someone explain how the for(; A--;) loop works. It doesn't have any increments, so shouldn't it run forever ?

```
int main(){
int A, B;

cout << "Anna t\x84htien m\x84\x84r\x84: "; //Give ammount of stars: 
cin >>A;
cout << endl;

for(; A--;){
    for(B = 0; A >= B; B++){
        cout << "* ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A--` is a decrement though

Comment: My issue with C and its siblings is that there are way too many possibilities for programmers to show off how clever they are. Like this kind of construction :)

Comment: If the entered value of `A` is positive, the loop will decrement it, and stop when the value being decremented is zero (so `A` will have value `-1` after the loop).    If the entered value is negative, the loop will run until `A` gets to the minimum value that an `int` can represent, and then exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: @fvu - I'd express your concern as "too many possibilities for programmers to TRY to show how clever they are".   The reality is that using these types of techniques is pretty dumb.

Comment: @Peter that's exactly what I mean. Thanks for the nuance.

Comment: @peter and  @ fvu Good drivers, know how car behaves when things go wrong, how did they learn it, by practice and/or experience. I have nothing against people who wrote this code or similar code, as long as they know what they are doing, the same way I have nothing against people drifting if they know what they are doing. My point is, I feel safer with driver who knows how to drift, and much much less safer with person who has no clue what a drift is.

Comment: @GRC - Your analogy is flawed.   The true good drivers also know their limits, and the limits of the vehicle, so have the sense to know when it is too dangerous for themselves or others to drift.    The programmers who use these techniques insist they are experts, but don't know the limits, don't know when the techniques are too dangerous for the usage, and are nowhere to be found when things go wrong.

Comment: @Peter in a way you are right, if this code is professional code than it is too dangerous, but if it is for purpose of learning where the limit is it is pretty good example to learn on.

Comment: In a sense of driving, I do not expect somebody to drift on public roads. But if I see somebody doing it on a track, and see that she/he knows how to do it, I would fall asleep easily while she/he is driving.

Comment: @GRC - this type of code doesn't tend to be written for learning purposes.    It tends to be written by people trying to demonstrate how smart they are, or trying to make themselves indispensable by writing code that breaks if other people touch it.   They are the people who drift past primary schools every morning while children are arriving for the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `for` loop runs for as long as its condition holds true. `A--` is equivalent to `A-- != 0`, so this is how long it's going to run.

One thing that is possibly nice to know is that a `for` loop can contain a lot more than mere incremental operations. *Usually*, it's something like `++i`, but that is no necessity. In school, you might not learn about how general `for` loops actually are, though.

Answer (score 1):

A-- is found in the condition part. As long as A != 0, the loop will execute. Since the -- operator is found after the variable, the decrement will be executed after the evaluation of A's value. Ex:

```
int A = 10;
//This loop will output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
for(;A--;){
  std::cout<<A<<" ";
}
A = 10;
//This loop will output: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
for(;--A;){
  std::cout<<A<<" ";
}
```

Comment: second one might have undefined behavior since you are not guarantied that comparison will take place before or after increment/decrement.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ a condition is true in every sense if it is non-zero. Let me clarify this by giving an example,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=5, b=-5;
    while(a)
    {
       cout<<"# ";
       a--;
    }

    cout<<"\n";

    while(b)
    {
       cout<<"* ";
       b++;
    }

return 0;
}
```

The output of the code will be:

```
# # # # # 
* * * * *
```

If you look into this, inside the **'a' while loop**, the condition is positive and it decrements until the value is '0'. Until the value is 0, the condition is said to be true and the flow of control executes the statements inside the while loop.

In the **'b' while loop**, it is clearly visible that even if 'b' is negative, the statements inside the while loop still executes until the value of 'b' increments to 0.

It is visible that every non-zero term is considered to be a true condition and a 0(zero) is considered to be a false condition. It is a mis-belief that (only) 1 is true and 0 is false.

The syntax for `for` loop is `for(declaration;condition;iteration)`. If one of the statements is missing, the loop will still continue to run. A `for loop` works as long as the condition is true. The flow of control, at first comes to the declaration, then checks the condition. If the condition is true, then it executes the statements in the scope of the loop. At last, the control comes to the iterative statements and again checks the condition. During the run-time, if at any moment the looping condition turns out to be `false`, then the control terminates the program or executes the statements just after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It goes until `A` reaches 0 and than will stop in the case that `A` was `>= 0` initially, otherwise, as pointed out by Eric, the behavior is undefined, as overflow will occur and it can end in few different ways.

Comment: If `A` is initially negative, the behavior is undefined, as overflow will occur. Possibilities include that It could loop forever, or it could wrap and stop, or it could trap.

Comment: @EricPostpischil +1 That's more precise. I will report it in the answer.